# Details' View with related data via LINQ using a custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Since I am new to ASP, sure am puzzled how to have a **List** of some specific columns of a model/table, derived via LINQ, be reflected on the relevant parent item's **Details** page.
Consider the example of two classes like:

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public string TournamentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TournamentDate { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamA")]
    public string TeamAID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamB")]
    public string TeamBID { get; set; }
    public Team TeamB { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public string TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Captain { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TeamA")]
    public ICollection<Tournament> TeamA { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TeamB")]
    public ICollection<Tournament> TeamB { get; set; }
}
```

The two tables have the details of Teams, and Tournaments played between them. Since the Tournament's model/table has more than one of it's field connected to the Team, the InverseProperty & relevant ForeignKeys are being used.

The **main object** is to present on a View a part of the details of a Team on the top but the relevant entries of the Tournaments being listed below the same.

Since a team, for example Team_1 might be existing in the TeamA column of the Tournament or even in the TeamB column, the question pops up as to how to have the same be presented in a manner like:

TeamID: ID_1

TeamName: Team_1

TeamCaptain: Captain1

**ID | Date | Competitor | Place**

**.... | ........ | ................ | .........**

**.... | ........ | ................ | .........**

For the same reason I came to deduce that I should use some special Model Class for the Custom Columns and thus added the following class:

```
public class GamesList
{
    public string TID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TDate { get; set; }
    public string TPlace { get; set; }
    public string TeamLinks { get; set; }
    public string TeamNames { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action like:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index2(string teamId)
    {
        var gamesList = ((from x in _context.Tournaments
                                .Where(x => x.TeamAID == teamId)
                                select new GamesList
                                {
                                    TID = x.TournamentID,
                                    TDate = x.TournamentDate,
                                    TeamLinks = x.TeamAID,
                                    TeamNames = x.TeamB.TeamName,
                                    TPlace = x.Place
                                })
                        .Concat(from x in _context.Tournaments
                                .Where(x => x.TeamBID == teamId)
                                select new GamesList
                                {
                                    TID = x.TournamentID,
                                    TDate = x.TournamentDate,
                                    TeamLinks = x.TeamBID,
                                    TeamNames = x.TeamA.TeamName,
                                    TPlace = x.Place
                                })).OrderBy(x => x.TDate);

        return View(await gamesList.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Thus, to have the same list being concatenated but with Team IDs & Names flipped, resulting in all the IDs compiled in a property named **TeamLinks** while names of the competitors lined up in the **TeamNames**.

Now, the said list can be presented by having a @model IEnumerable **but** as the main goal specified how to present such a list under the **Details** of the Team (i.e. the one also possessing the TeamID == teamId)?

Thanks.

Comment: read up on view models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with a view model(s) that represents what you want in the view

```
public class TeamVM
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Captain { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TournamentVM> Tournaments { get; set; }
}
public class TournamentVM
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Competitor { get; set; }
}
```

Then query you database to get the team (by its `TeamID`) including the collections of `Tournament` and map the result to your view models. Using LinqToEntities

```
Team team = db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamID == teamId).FirstOrDefault();
if (team == null) { ... }; // error

TeamVM model = new TeamVM
{
    ID = team.TeamID,
    Name = team.TeamName,
    Captain = team.Captain,
    // join the collections into a new collection of TournamentVM
    Tournaments = team.TeamA.Where(x => x.TeamAID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamB.TeamName
    }).Concat(team.TeamB.Where(x => x.TeamBID == team.TeamID).Select(x => new TournamentVM
    {
        ID = x.TournamentID,
        Date = x.TournamentDate,
        Place = x.Place,
        Competitor = x.TeamA.TeamName
    })).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model TeamVM
....
<div>@Model.ID</div>
....
<table>
   <thead> ... </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach(var item in Model.Tournaments)
       {
           <tr>
               <td>@item.ID</td>
               <td>@item.Date</td>
               ....
           </tr>
       }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Using the same led me to find an error at the end of the action, i.e. **.OrderBy(x => x.Date);** and removed the **;** in the end. However, I am still receiving an error like: **ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: source**. What code be the reason?

Comment: The `;` was just a typo (now edited). I have no idea about your `ArgumentNullException` - its not related to the code I showed. Where are you getting that exception

Comment: Thanks again buddy. However, the exception reflects on the webpage highlighting the line of the controller action: **TeamVM model = new TeamVM**. Sure would have presented the screenshot but find myself unable to insert an image in this comment.

Comment: Try and narrow it down. I assumed your have debugged `Team team = db.Teams....` to ensure your getting valid data? Comment out the `Tournaments = team.TeamA ....` bit etc to see where the exception is

Comment: Have just noticed that your navigational properties are not `virtual` so there may be an issue with lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen! The idea of creating auxiliary models of requisite shapes and then mapping the original worked out to be the best. However, I think I should highlight it was not the lack of **virtual** terms but rather the absence of **Include()** statement for the Tournaments. It was reading out your praiseworthy solution provided, **repetitively** that I realized that you although had used the used the  words **including the collections of Tournament** but hadn't done so in the code. Thanks again.

Comment: But if you did have `virtual` and EF configured correctly, using `.Include()` would not be necessary :)

Comment: Sure do admire your expert grip @Stephen, however, regretfully not finding any way to insert the code in comments. Don't know whether to edit the original question? I have just noted that I am using both, the **Virtual** as well as **Include()**. Besides the same it is no doubt the Tournaments which being commented out did reflect the result, **but** I have just found out that even upon using the Include statement I am unable to bring back the Competitors' Names. In the portion **team.TeamA** I am unable to bring the names of the TeamB? Am I allowed to edit the original question & provide code

Comment: You should be asking a new question, just concentrating on the issue of your query not loading the data you expect (and perhaps include a snapshot of your data to prove its actually there)